# reading data with BigQueryReader in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-bigquery

I tried to use the BigQueryReader from Tensorflow but I don't succeed in actually reading the data. This is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib.cloud.python.ops.bigquery_reader_ops import BigQueryReader
import time

features = dict(
    weight_pounds=tf.FixedLenFeature([1], tf.float32),
    mother_age=tf.FixedLenFeature([1], tf.float32),
    father_age=tf.FixedLenFeature([1], tf.float32),
    gestation_weeks=tf.FixedLenFeature([1], tf.float32))

millis = int(round(time.time() * 1000))

reader = BigQueryReader(project_id="bigquery-public-data",
    dataset_id="samples",
    table_id="natality",
    timestamp_millis=millis,
    num_partitions=10,
    features=features)

queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(reader.partitions())
row_id, examples_serialized = reader.read(queue)
examples = tf.parse_example(examples_serialized, features=features)
```

When executing this code sample I get:

```
File "/home/juta/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.py", line 659, in _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl
    raise ValueError(err.message)
ValueError: Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 0 for 'ParseExample_3/ParseExample' (op: 'ParseExample') with input shapes: [], [0], [], [], [], [], [0], [0], [0], [0].
```

The parsing is probably failing because reader.read(queue) seems to return empty objects:

```
ReaderRead(key=<tf.Tensor 'ReaderRead:0' shape=() dtype=string>, value=<tf.Tensor 'ReaderRead:1' shape=() dtype=string>)
```

Why is the reader not returning any data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reader is not returning *empty* objects: it is returning *scalars* (i.e. tensors with rank 0, or an "empty" shape). See the TensorFlow [programmers guide on tensor shapes](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/dims_types) for more details.

The shape error "Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 0" indicates that the [`tf.parse_example()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/parse_example) op expects a *vector* (rank 1 tensor) as input, rather than a scalar. There are at least two possible solutions:

1. Use the [`tf.parse_single_example()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/parse_single_example) op, which expects a scalar input, instead.
2. Reshape the value returned by `reader.read()` into a vector, for example using [`tf.expand_dims(examples_serialized, 0)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/expand_dims).

Comment: Thanks, I can now use the tensors to access the values from bigquery by using `example = tf.parse_single_example(examples_serialized, features=features)`. However I still don't get actual values. When running the session it gets stuck and I get no return value. Any idea why `sess.run(example)` is not returning anything?

Comment: Have you called `tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess)`?

Answer (score 0):

I have also had the same problem and have tried three approaches. The following solutions should all run:

```
examples = tf.parse_example(tf.expand_dims(examples_serialized, 0), features=features)
## or
examples = tf.parse_example([examples_serialized], features=features)
## or
examples = tf.parse_single_example(examples_serialized, features=features)
```

However, even if this code runs, the following code will just hang without producing any output:

```
weight_pounds = examples['weight_pounds']    
with tf.Session() as session:
    print(session.run(weight_pounds))
```

Speculating a bit, perhaps this problems stems from `tf.train.string_input_producer` now being deprecated in favor of `tf.data` so perhaps this usage is no longer supported.  On the other hand, I have been unable to find any documentation on how to use `tf.data` with BigQuery. I tried something like this:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(reader.read(queue))
```

But this returns a `IndexError: list index out of range` error